# Is my app's app store URL known when it is in the "Pending Developer Release" state?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a free version of my app in the app store. A while ago I finished writing the full version. For my private reasons I don't want to release the full version just yet, so I selected "Manually release this version". Now, the app is in "Pending Developer Release" state. I can release it whenever I like.

I want to add a link in the free version to the full version. Something like "Get the full version!" button. But I don't know what the link is because the full version has not been released.

I see a button called "View on App Store" in iTunesConnect. This is the url it took me to:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[my app name]/id[my app id]?ls=1&mt=8
```

Is this link a real link or is it just a placeholder. Will it change when I release my app?

Comment: You have the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/40982879?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the link that your app will be living on. It will be broken and not working until you app is released on the App Store. Apple generates the link once you register your App in iTunesconnect and this link is unique to your app. 
To answer your second question, no, it will not change once your app is released. This will be associated with your app forever(unless you change your app name).